# how to arrange the row() in the button of the screen ( i want to put screen navigating icon in the button )

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, widget

```
Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        //    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FloatingActionButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              //ClearSession();
                              if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                                Navigator.pop(context, true);
                              }
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          Home(22.0, 22.0)));
                            }
                            // Add your onPressed code here!
                            ,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            child: const Icon(Icons.home),
                          ),
                          FloatingActionButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              //ClearSession();
                              if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                                Navigator.pop(context, true);
                              }
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          const Calender()));
                            }
                            // Add your onPressed code here!
                            ,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            child: const Icon(Icons.calendar_month),
                          ),
                          FloatingActionButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              //ClearSession();
                              if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
                                Navigator.pop(context, true);
                              }
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) =>
                                          const Community()));
                            },
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            child: const Icon(Icons.article_rounded),
                          ),
                          FloatingActionButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              // Add your onPressed code here!
                            },
                            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                            child: const Icon(
                                Icons.settings_accessibility_sharp),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

it should be compatible with all types of screens regardless of screen size
I don't want to use padding because it only works for  some screen , not  for all type of the screen
the icons are in the middle of the screen,

I want to put all of them in the button of the screen

[image: this is the current position of icons]

it should be compatible with all types of screens regardless of screen size
I don't want to use padding because it only works for  some screen,not  for all type of the screen the icons are in the middle of the screen, I want to put all of them in the button of the screen

Comment: you can put your row inside a stack with positioned widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `scaffold()` and after that put your `Row()` in `floatingActionButton` property like this:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: ...
  body:...
  floatingActionButton: // your Row()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

it's easy you can put all the buttons using   bottomNavigationBar which is a property available to scaffold widget